# iPhone Jabber/XMPP client... "TURN Connection failed"

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to build a simple Jabber client.
I have downloaded this sample project, which uses *xmpp-framework* https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS
I am running it in the iOS Simulator. I have installed Openfire locally so that I can interact with a user logged into iChat.

Unfortunately the app only *receives* messages. It fails in sending messages giving the error "TURN Connection failed!".

This is the code attempting to connect:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tView.delegate = self;
    self.tView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];

    JabberClientAppDelegate *del = [self appDelegate];
    del._messageDelegate = self;

    [self.messageField becomeFirstResponder];

    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"user@server.local"];

    NSLog(@"Attempting TURN connection to %@", jid);

    TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];

    [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];

    [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [turnSocket release];   
}
```

And those are the methods called on success/failure:

```
- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket 
{   
    NSLog(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");
    NSLog(@"You now have a socket that you can use to send/receive data to/from the other person.");

    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender 
{   
    NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");
    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
}
```

Can anyone please help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use TURN for normal messaging.  TURN is required for media streaming only.  Just use [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).  There are some good getting-started guides.

Next, use code of this nature to create and send stanzas:

```
XMPPMessage *msg = [XMPPMessage message];
[msg addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[msg addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"foo@example.com"];
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body" stringValue:@"Hello"];
[msg addChild:body];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:msg];
```

Note that `msg` is just a subclass of NSXMLElement, so you can modify the XML at will to craft the protocol you're going to send.

Comment: Could you please point some out? I've only found documentation on how to start a connection –never on how to send a message. Thank you very much.

Comment: Turns out TURN is not needed -the error is unrelated to the inability of sending messages. I moved the sendMessage method to the App Delegate and... it started working. I don't know why. But it works.

Comment: @Joe:- Can you give me refrence for integration XMPP in iOS , any link or doc ? I am out of luck for this.

Comment: Hi Joe, could you please give me some way to send file in XMPP ?

Comment: See the list of XEPs at http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/.  Start with XEP-0096: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html